# How to print a PDF converted from HTML in Letter Format without margins using Edge?

Tags: html, printing, media-queries, microsoft-edge, page-size

I have a PDF Report generated using HTML. The PDF was generated in A3 format. I am trying to print the report in Letter Format using MS Edge. It prints with margin on both left and right side.

Can anyone please let me know how can i remvoe margin while printing ?

I used the below styles but there is no luck.

```
@media print {
 @page : {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
}

@page { margin: 0! important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no problems in doing what you want without any settings
Edge will read A3 seen on left and as seen on right Edge will print Letter at any orientation and scale. However since there are no margins in a PDF it cannot shift the contents without a Printer Application. The text can just as easily be spilling outside the Media /Ink areas. So the print "margins" in this case are already at 0 per your attempted code.

Converting one size of PDF to another is not as simple as basic reprint in all cases. The function you need to remove the voids around the "EDGE"s is a PDF cropping tool.

[image]

OR a good scalable print driver
[image]
[image]